# Jira software: trigger a script on release?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I'd like, on "Release" button pressed, to trigger a server-side script of my own. I don't need to use big thing like Jenkins, I just need to run a simple script.

I looked into the documentation and found "Listeners" on earlier versions, but there is nothing in the doc for latest version.

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you wrap your remote script in an HTTP interface and trigger it via a webhook? https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks

Comment: I have to make some test before validating the answer. It looks promising, but also very limited for release, as the hook does not provide useful data with the release.

Comment: @ConstantinGuay what other data do you need? Hook itself provides limited data but you could query JIRA back via rest API to get more information.

Comment: @PetroSemeniuk I need, per example, the label of the deployed version. The id is not easy to use outside Jira. I need it to tag the commit deployed per example.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the script runner plugin for jira, which can execute a script with a ssh on a server or whatever you like